# read a specific number of chars from stdin

Tags: c++, file, file-descriptor

HI

I'm writing a program that acts as a server and has the ability to interact with the user via the terminal. if i read from the stdin i want up to 140 chars.
if the user enters more than 140 i would like to take only the first 140 chars and ignore the rest.

i try something like the following code:

```
struct timeval timeout;
fd_set readings;
char buf[140];


while (1) {
    timeout.tv_sec = 15;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    FD_ZERO(&readings);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO,&readings);

    int rv = select(STDIN_FILENO+1,&readings,NULL,NULL,&timeout);
    if (rv<0) {
        cout << "ERROR select\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    if (rv==0) {
        cout << "Still Waiting...\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "A key was pressed\n";
        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO,&readings)) {
            int num = read(STDIN_FILENO,&buf,140);
            buf[num]='\0';
            cout << buf << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is - when i enter more than 140 chars, the first 140 chars are printed, but then read() reads the rest of the data in the next iteration and prints it .
how do i clear the stdin so that the rest of the data will be ignored in the next iteration?

thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the only choice is to read the characters and discard them until end-of-line is reached.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably modify your solution to use [readsome()](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/readsome/).

```
char c[140];
cin.readsome(&c[0], 140);
```

Or keep what you have and use [ignore](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/)

Answer (score 0):

Read all the input text in a pointer, then extract the first 140 characters, and then delete the pointer again to be ready to the next request.

Comment: how to i read the unknown amount of data to a pointer without allocating space to hold it?

Comment: you could take the width of the input stream, reallocate the pointer variable with the width + 1 characters, and then read the input stream into de pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like that:

```
char buf[256];//what ever
...
int num = read(STDIN_FILENO,&buf,256);
if (num > 140) num = 140;
buf[num]='\0';
cout << buf << endl;
```